# Apex test 3% code coverage,

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

Need Help! I have a test class GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller_Tester with 3 objects, location(master), groups(child) and meeting(grand child). The SOQL query is returning a rowthe Apex coverage is still 3%. the methods I've tested I can see in my code clearly, How do you make changePasswordController forgotPasswordController etc Any help would be extremely useful, I'm a newbie this is my  first test class.

```
@isTest
public with sharing class GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller_Tester {

static testMethod void TestcustomGroupLookup () {

    Location__c objLocation = new Location__c();
    objLocation.name = 'test';
    insert objLocation;
    System.debug('::::objLocation.Id:::: ' + objLocation.Id);

    Group__c objGroup = new Group__c();
    objGroup.name = 'test';
    objGroup.Location__c = objLocation.Id;      
    insert objGroup;
    System.debug('::::objGroup.Id:::: ' + objGroup.Id);

    Meeting__c objMeeting = new Meeting__c();
    objMeeting.Group__c = objGroup.id;
    objMeeting.GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s =-0.39348930;
    objMeeting.GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s = 37.00245300;
    objMeeting.Meeting_Date__c = date.today();
    objMeeting.Credit_Repaid__c = 100;
    objMeeting.Credit_Sales__c = 1000;
    objMeeting.Cash_In_Hand__c = 10;
    objMeeting.Stock_Value__c = 100;
    objMeeting.Assets_Bought__c =100;
    objMeeting.Cash_Sales__c = 100;
    //objMeeting.Location__c = objLocation.id;
    //objMeeting.Name = 'test';
    insert objMeeting;
    System.debug('::::objMeeting.Id::::' + objMeeting.Id);
    System.debug('::::objMeeting.Group__c::::' + objMeeting.Group__c);
    //System.debug('::::objMeeting.Group__r.Id::::' + objMeeting.Group__r.Id);

    //construct controller
    GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller controller = new GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller();

    PageReference myVfPage = Page.BOMAgrpLandingPage;
    Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);   
    Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', objGroup.id);
    System.debug('::::id::::' + id);

    List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList = new List<Meeting__c>();
    List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList2 = new List<Meeting__c>();

    MeetingsList = [SELECT Name, Group__c, Meeting_Date__c, GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__c =:id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1 ];
    MeetingsList2 =[SELECT Name, Group__c, Meeting_Date__c, GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__c =:id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c DESC LIMIT 1 ];
    //System.debug('MeetingsList2 Group__r.Id: ' + MeetingsList2.Group__r.Id);
}
}
```

[image: Code Coverage]

Comment: Hey highfive,  still 0% coverage, in the system Debug the Page id is showing up as null, no SOQL querry returns

Comment: Test methods are written in order to cover other operational Apex code. What code are you trying to cover with this test class?

Comment: The code i was trying to cover was a custom controller for a visualforce page. updating my question so you can see it. @Jeremy Nottingham

Comment: Looks to me like you have 100% coverage on the class you are targeting. To increase the overall run ALL tests. If the other code does not have test coverage then you may have to write separate test classes.

Comment: All other classes from the code coverage screenshot are autogenerated after activating force.com sites. They should come with some unit tests. It should not be your concern to test foreign code. What happens, if you are running all tests? Does the coverage rise?

Comment: Thanks guys,  finally worked. had not run other tests. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use assertions!
2. Select all objects from MeetingsList and print it with System.debug

I mean, instead of

```
MeetingsList = [SELECT Name, Group__r.Id, Meeting_Date__c, GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__r.Id =:id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1];

MeetingsList2 =[SELECT Name, Group__r.Id, Meeting_Date__c, GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__r.Id =:id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];
```

put this line

```
MeetingsList = [SELECT Name, Group__r.Id, Meeting_Date__c,
GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s
FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__r.Id =:id];
```

I assume you're not using @isTest(SeeAllData=true) and therefore you'll see the data created in isolation (only these objects that are visible in unit tests).

And check the debug log.

Comment: Hey BigBallOfMud,
Did the edits you suggested and now the SOQl query is returning one row, thanks for the tip. However the Apex code coverage is still 0% coverage and I am completely lost as to why. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Kollo, if you want to cover the controller class you need to call the controller class. The code coverage is 0% just because it's not called. The only thing your test method does now is test data preparation, see the example (unit test at the botton) http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm for better understanding of common unit test structure please read http://martinfowler.com/bliki/GivenWhenThen.html

Comment: one more clue: //given: code with test data creation // when" calling controller method // then: ensure that expected data is created (i.e. assertion checking that record exists)

Comment: Thanks @BigBallOfMud! Finally got something. Managed to call the controller class, still need achieve more coverage, but definetly a step in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the existing data for your unit testing, you have to use `(seeAllData=true)` in the annotation as in this [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm).

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public with sharing class GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller_Tester {
   //your code
}
```

But it's not a good practice to hard code existing record ids and perform unit test on those because you can't predict how long those records will be there in the system. At anytime these records can be deleted and your test class will fail. Also when you are deploying these Ids will not available in other organizations. So there also your test class will be failed.

Best way is to create some test data in the test class and perform the unit test with using those test data.
Read some documentations on [adding test classes](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_test.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Update: I didn't understand the original question. As you have noted, you have to Run All Tests to get the coverage for the entire Salesforce org. If you only run one testclass, it will just show the coverage for that one set of tests.

By the way, I note the following about your test code:

I believe you need to move the controller construction to happen *after* you set the Id in the URL parameters and PageReference.

```
PageReference myVfPage = Page.BOMAgrpLandingPage;
Test.setCurrentPage(myVfPage);   
Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', objGroup.id);
System.debug('::::id::::' + id);

//construct controller
GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller controller = new GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller();
```

This way the constructor runs with the parameter in place. In your original code, the constructor couldn't possibly know what record to operate on.